# Condition only on some of the columns or different conditions for each column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

[image: weight and height of names]

I want to run a query that will give me (1) the average of *all the rows* in the 'weight' column and (2) the count *only the rows* of people over 170 cm tall.
How do I insert a conditions only for one column?

And how do I insert different conditions for each column (For example the same condition for the 'height' column but the average only for the 'weight' under 60 KG)

And finally how do I add another general condition ? for example, to receive this data only for people whose name begins with the letter a?

I actually need to make those 2 queries in 1 query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_higher_than_170 
FROM `Example'
HAVING COUNT(height) > 170

SELECT AVG(weight) as avg_weight
FROM `Example'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
create temp table data as(
 
select "adfa" name, 75 weight, 176 height union all
select "afsdf", 56,182 union all
select "earf", 52,192 union all
select "vasd", 50,164 union all
select "qasd", 71,169
);
```

**solution 1**

```
with cte as(
 select * from data where name like 'a%'
)
 
select
(select count(*) from cte where height > 170) num_higher_than_170
,(select avg(weight) from cte where weight > 60) avg_weight ;
```

**solution 2**

```
select
(select count(*) from data where name like 'a%' and height > 170) num_higher_than_170
,(select avg(weight) from data where name like 'a%' and weight > 60) avg_weight ;
```